# Problemas con Map Fragment en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragment, google-places

Estoy queriendo desarrollar una **app** que despliegue un mapa con un `Floating Action Button` el cual permita al usuario agregar marcadores en el mapa según un `intent` de Places.

Me encuentro actualmente con una falla en el mapa al salir del `intent` de busqueda de Places dado que no me permite agregar el marcador porque la referencia al `map` se torna `null`.

Probé hacerlo mediante una `interfaz` pero para que llegue a los mismos resultados de `null reference` cuando tengo que agregar el `marker` en `myMap`.

**Aca la actividad**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private LatLng nueva_pos;
private String nombre_marc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "KEY");

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onSearchCalled();
        }
    });

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MapFragment(), "mapFragment")
            .commit();

}

public void onSearchCalled() {
    // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
    List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
    // Start the autocomplete intent.
    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).setCountry("AR") //Argentina
            .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);

            //añadir marcador en nueva ubicación
            nueva_pos = place.getLatLng();
            nombre_marc = place.getName();
            MapFragment.getInstance().NuevoMarcador(nueva_pos,nombre_marc);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID: " + place.getId() + "address:" + place.getAddress() + "Name:" + place.getName() + " latlong: " + place.getLatLng(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // do query with address

        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + "Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Aca el fragmento**

Probé agregando un metodo en el `OnResume` que haga la llamada al `onMapReady` nuevamente para que se actualice la instancia del `myMa`p pero no tuve resultados.

```
    public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap myMap;
private static final String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=key";
private double longitud, latitud;

public static MapFragment getInstance() {
    return new MapFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    myMap = googleMap;

    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try{

        jsonObject.put("homeMobileCountryCode","54")
                .put("homeMobileNetworkCode", "070")
                .put("radioType", "gsm")
                .put("carrier","Movistar")
                .put("considerIp", "true");

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{

                JSONObject jsonCoord = response.getJSONObject("location");

                latitud = Double.parseDouble(jsonCoord.getString("lat"));
                longitud = Double.parseDouble(jsonCoord.getString("lng"));
                LatLng posicion = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
                myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posicion).title("You're here!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
                myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(posicion));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitud: " + latitud + "\n" + "Longitud: " + longitud, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ocurrió un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
    if (myMap == null) {
        this.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setupMapIfNeeded();

}

public void NuevoMarcador(LatLng pos, String nombre_lugar) {
    setupMapIfNeeded();
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(nombre_lugar).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que la instancia del mapa y sus elementos tengan un valor diferente de null, el mapa  debe estar cargado y esto se define al llamarse el método:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    myMap = googleMap;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Desde el Fragment podrías llamar al intent.